# If integral is zero and function is continuous and non negative, then what about the function?

Tags: calculus, integration

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $f(x)≥0$ on $[a,b]$ and $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) =0$$

then prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

I tried with Riemann's definite integral definition but couldn't proceed

Comment: Use the contra-reciprocal for demonstrating  that.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, and $f(x_0)>0$, there is an interval $I$ containing $x_0$ where $f$ is positive (elementary exercise- see Spivak's Caclulus). On this interval, integral of $f$ is positive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**: Suppose that $f$ were not identically zero, and choose $x_0 \in (a, b)$ for which $f(x_0) > 0$. Then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that

$$|x - x_0| < \epsilon \implies f(x) > \frac{1}{2} f(x_0)$$

Try considering a partition of the interval containing the interval $[x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon]$, and compute a lower sum.

Comment: Is there a reason why it was chosen $f(x)>\dfrac12f(x_0)$ instead of $f(x)>f(x_0)$?

Comment: @User1618 He has chosen an $\epsilon$ so that $f(x)$ lies in the $f(x_0)/2$ radius interval around $f(x_0)$. If, for example, $f(x_0)$ was an upper bound, then no such $\epsilon$ exists.

Answer (score 33):

Something more easy. If $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ then we can define a map $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ such that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(x) dx$ and $F'=f$.

We have $F(x)≥0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$ because $f(x)\geq0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$.

Also $F$ is increasing because $f(x)≥0$ and we have $F(a)=F(b)=0$, thus $F$ is constant and especially $F(x)=0$.

So $f(x)=0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: If $f$ is only integrable, then you can't say $F'=f$. The Second Fundamental Theorem requires that $f$ be continuous. For example, if $f$ was nonzero at a single point, then it would still integrate to 0.

Comment: How does F being increasing and nonnegative make F(b) and F(a) equal to 0

Comment: Haha, I have the same question as @angelo086 (wasn't stalking you. just recognised your username hahaha)

Comment: cc @kbolino....

Comment: @Haha Can u help me in this question? If $f$ belongs to $C[0, 1]$. Determine the cases where the given condition implies that $f$ is identically zero.

Case 1     $\int\ x^nf(x) =0$     for all non negative n

Case 2    $\int\ f(x)Cosnx =0$    for all non negative n

Case 3  $\int\ f(x)Sinnx =0$    for all positive n

Comment: @sani Asking random questions in comments is not a reasonable way how to deal with the question ban. (Neither is asking questions on other sites, where they are off-topic.) You have enough reputation to [talk in chat](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), so you can try to ask there. For example [Calculus and analysis chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150/2017/5/28) or [the main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/36) might be a reasonable place for the question from your comment.

Comment: But this is  not a random question...This is very much relevant to the main question..However If u know the answer U could have helped me with lesser effort..@MartinSleziak

Comment: hiii@Martin Sleziak Do u have any Idea How can I proceed?????

Comment: This proof is wrong. We can't ensure the derivative with continuity.

Comment: @RudikRobertoRompich you can check that if f is continuous, F so defined is always differentiable.

Comment: @ArticChar, counterexample: Tagaki, and Weierstrass function. Continuity does not imply being differentiable. There is even a book called "Continuous Nowhere Differentiable Functions" from Springer.

Comment: @RudikRobertoRompich of course there are functions $f$ that is continuous but not differentiable. But for any continuous $f$, $F$ is differentiable.